# An adjoint with unit the identity, Does it imply counit identity?

Tags: category-theory

I have the next doubt:

If $S:A\rightarrow C$ is faithful, full and surjective in objects (for each $c\in Obj(C)$ $Sa=c$ for $a\in Obj(A)$) then we have the adjunction $\langle T,S, 1,\varepsilon\rangle: C\rightarrow A$ with unit the identity.

I already proved that proposition, my doubt is: Does it imply counit identity?

I think the answer is yes.

We have the natural transformation $1=\eta:I_{C}\rightarrow ST$ and $\varepsilon:TS\rightarrow I_{A}$, then by the triangular identity we have:

$\begin{eqnarray}
1_{Sa}&=&S\varepsilon_{a}\cdot \eta_{Sa}\\
&=&S\varepsilon_{a}\cdot1_{Sa}\\
&=&S\varepsilon_{a}
\end{eqnarray}$

Because $S$ is full and faithful, It follows that $\varepsilon_{a}=1_{a}$

Thank you for your time.

Comment: I thoght about that which work if $S$ is and equivalence of categories. The if that happens then the Counit is the identity.

Comment: The last line seems to be wrong. In order to use faithfulness you need $1_a$ and $\epsilon_a$ to be in the same hom set i.e. you already need to know that $TS=I_A$.

Comment: @Nex So... the ony thing  I can conclude is that $\varepsilon_{a}$ is an isomorphism?

Comment: In my comment: $TS=I_A$ should be $TS(a)=a$.

Comment: @Liddo For any category $A$ if we take $C$ to be a skeleton of $A$, couldn't we find a functor $S:A\to C$ satisfying your conditions?

Answer (score 2):

This answer is really due to Nex in the comments, but so that the question doesn't remain apparently open: the existence of a fully faithful and surjective functor in one direction by no means implies the existence of a surjective functor of any kind in the other direction, because the domain and codomain could have object collections of wildly different sizes. For instance, the groupoid of all one-element sets surjects fully faithfully onto the final category (one object and one morphism,) but the first category is not even small!